# sort linked list using vector for vowels and consonants

Tags: c++, linked-list

I was trying to arrange vowels and consonants in a linked list by using 2 vectors to store and update the pointers in stacks.
However none of the cout is working in below code snippet, where am I going wrong?
Even the cout in main is before arrange function call and that too is not displaying.

```
using namespace std;
bool r(char a,char b)
{
    return a>b;
}

struct node{
    char a;
    struct node* next;
};
struct node* head;
void push(char data)
{
    node* temp=new node;
    temp->a=data;

    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=temp;
        temp->next=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        temp->next=head;
        head=temp;
    }

}

void arrange()
{
    vector<node*> q1;
    vector<node*> q2;
    node* temp=head;

    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        if(temp->a=='a'||temp->a=='e')
            q1.push_back(temp);
        else
            q2.push_back(temp);

        temp=temp->next;
    }
    
    head=q1[0];

    cout<<head->next->a<<q1.size();

    for(int i=0;i<=q1.size();i++)
    {
        if(i==q1.size())
            q1[i]->next=q2[0];
        else
            q1[i]->next=q1[i+1];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<=q2.size();i++)
    {
        if(i==q2.size())
            q2[i]->next=NULL;
        else
            q2[i]->next=q2[i+1];
    }

    node* t=head;

    while(t!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<t->a;
        t=t->next;
    }

}

int main() 
{ 
    
    head=NULL;
    push('a');
    push('b');
    push('c');
    push('d');
    push('e');
    push('f');

    node* temp=head;

    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<temp->a;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    
    arrange();

    return 0; 
}
```

only when I remove the for loops in arrange function, cout seems to be working fine

Comment: Just to mention it, there're also many other problems that may trigger problems in `arrange()`, also, there're some better ways to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Do test `if (cout)` to see whether there is a problem with your `cout`.  If there is a problem, report it to `cerr`.

Answer (score 0):

First, this code works fine on my laptop before `arrange()`, and it stuck for a sec, then broke down.

I didn't go through the code carefully, but I wildly guess that it's because you try to get access to a `nullptr`.

As for the invisibility of output before `arrange()`, maybe it's just because you didn't use `std::cout << std::endl`, which flushes the output buffer, meanwhile outputs a line-break. `std::cout` does not output characters right after you `std::cout` it, instead, it puts input into a built-in buffer. And when the buffer is full filled, it outputs all the contents, then loads in the remaining parts.

You can refer to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush) for more detail.(See the paragraph below **Example**)

Normally, the buffer also flushes when something wrong happened, which is the current situation and also makes me a little bit confused.